# Custom ListView item is not scrolling. only first item displayed

Tags: android, listview

All items in the listview is not shown.only first item is shown.after i deleted the 1st item then i can see the second one.i cant see the all items so that i can scroll.i changed layout height as match parent but it didnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

items which need to be displayed in list view is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#a750d3"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#a750d3"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#a750d3"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#a750d3"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_go"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#99cc00"
            android:text="go" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_del"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff4444"
            android:text="Delete" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a height of linear layout of list item is wrap_content...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

...